# ¿Como puedo mostrar un texto que varíe dependiendo de la respuesta al momento de realizar una suma?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo el siguiente fragmento en js que genera una sumatoria de unos "li" seleccionados en HTML.

```
    scorad_blatt = 0;

result_enabled = 0;

function ManagePercent(object, op) {

    original = parseFloat($(".circle").html());
    switch(op) {
        case "add":
        original += cosVal[object];
        break;
    case "reduce":
        original -= cosVal[object];
        break;
    }
    $(".circle").html(Math.min(original,100));
    schau_ergebnis_doch_sichtbar();
}

$(" ul.regla2 li").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".whiteg").removeClass("whiteg");
    $(this).toggleClass("whiteg");
    schau_ergebnis_doch_sichtbar();
});
$("ul.regla li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".white").removeClass("white");
    $(this).toggleClass("white");
    schau_ergebnis_doch_sichtbar();
});

$("#resultado").click(function() {
    $("#cerrarResultado").show();
    result_enabled = -1;
    $(this).addClass("verResultado");
    if (scorad_blatt) {
        scorad_rechnen();
    } else {
        easi_rechnen();
    }
});

$("#cerrarResultado").click(function() {
    result_enabled = 0;
    $(this).hide();
    // reset values
    if (scorad_blatt) {
        reset_wert();
    } else {
        reset_wert2();
    }
})

function reset_wert() {
    $("#resultado").removeClass("verResultado");
    $("#resultado").html( i18n[sprache]["ausrechnen"]);
    nuke();
    $(".circle").html(0);
    $("ul.regla li").find("a").removeClass("white");
}

function reset_wert2() {
    $("#resultado").removeClass("verResultado");
    $("#resultado").html( i18n[sprache]["ausrechnen"] );
    $("ul.regla2").find("li").removeClass("whiteg");
}

function schau_ergebnis_doch_sichtbar() {
    if (result_enabled) {
        if (scorad_blatt) {
            scorad_rechnen();
        } else {
            easi_rechnen();
        }
    }
}

function easi_rechnen() {
    var preguntaUno = 0;
    var preguntaDos = 0;
    var preguntaTres = 0;
    var preguntaCuatro = 0;
    var preguntaCinco = 0;
    var preguntaSeis = 0;
    var preguntaSiete = 0;

    $("#pregunta_uno").find(".whiteg").map(function() {
        preguntaUno = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
        return preguntaUno;
    });
    $("#pregunta_dos").find(".whiteg").map(function() {
        preguntaDos = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
        return preguntaDos;
    });
    $("#pregunta_tres").find(".whiteg").map(function() {
        preguntaTres = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
        return preguntaTres;
    });
    $("#pregunta_cuatro").find(".whiteg").map(function() {
        preguntaCuatro = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
        return preguntaCuatro;
    });
    $("#pregunta_cinco").find(".whiteg").map(function() {
        preguntaCinco = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
        return preguntaCinco;
    });
    $("#pregunta_seis").find(".whiteg").map(function() {
        preguntaSeis = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
        return preguntaSeis;
    });
    $("#pregunta_siete").find(".whiteg").map(function() {
        preguntaSiete = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
        return preguntaSiete;
    });
    resultv =  parseFloat(preguntaUno + preguntaDos + preguntaTres + preguntaCuatro + preguntaCinco + preguntaSeis + preguntaSiete)

    $("#resultado").html( resultv);    
}
```

Este es uno de los fragmentos, que en el front del sitio el usuario va seleccionar y así generar la sumatoria

```
                        <ul class="regla2" id="pregunta_uno">
                            <li data-value="0"><a>Ningún<br/> día</a></li>
                            <li data-value="1"><a>1-2<br/> días</a></li>
                            <li data-value="2"><a>3-4<br/> días</a></li>
                            <li data-value="3"><a>5-6<br/> días</a></li>
                            <li data-value="4"><a>Todos<br/> los días</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Al final la respuesta pasa por el id "resultado", cambiando el texto "CALCULAR" a mostrarme el resultado.

```
        <div class="headertop container row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="result-block">
                <p id="texto_resultado">RESULTADO:</p>
                <a id="resultado" class="btn btn-scorad">Calcular</a>
                <a id="cerrarResultado" class="btn-result">X</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Lo que busco que es que al momento de realizar esta suma, se muestre un texto en un div que varié dependiendo el rango en que se encuentre el resultado, es decir que si saco 7 muestre un texto "regular" si saco un 28 "muy regular" y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer una función que reciba el resultado y por cada nota devuelva un 
   mensaje:

```
function mensajeResultado(resultado){
          // se usa floor() para redondear
          resultado = Math.floor(resultado);

          switch(resultado){
            case 7: return "regular";
            case 8: return "muy regular";

          }

        }
```

Luego la usas así:

```
$("#mostrarResultado").html(mensajeResultado(resultv));
```

Comment: Me complique con los cases pero lo pude resolver con una secuencia de if y elses en base a tu ayuda.